# Error with the form "Your Answer"

Tags: bug, answers

I would like to answer this question:

[Applications of the Spectral Theorem to Quantum Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9551/applications-of-the-spectral-theorem-to-quantum-mechanics?rq=1)

But, I cannot. I insert my answer in the form "Your Answer", I click on "Post Your Answer" and then after a while (even 5 minutes) I receive an error message.
Could someone help me?

Comment: Might help to post the error message?

Comment: OK, now I re-try and I write here the outcome. please wait (thanks)

Comment: Please wait, it is still "working" after 6 minutes...

Comment: ...after 15 minutes I received the following error message, written in red: "an error occurred submitting the answer." I do not think it could help much.

Comment: @VM9: Restart your browser? Clear the cache? That error occurs when you're unable to contact the server farm. But, I guess it doesn't apply here. Actually, what browser do you use?

Comment: @Crazy Buddy: I use firefox. Indeed I tried to restart it without success. Now I try to clear the cache...

Comment: ....it does not work anyway :(

Comment: I had something like this happen yesterday, I think. It went away after a few hours.

Comment: I just discovered that my problem (that pointed out in my question above and that persists today) only concerns  "Applications of the Spectral Theorem to Quantum Mechanics" since, as I checked two mins ago, I am allowed sending other answers regarding other questions.